# Unset canceling out if statement

Tags: php

I have set a session named errors. When i check if it's set and then call a function then unset the session variable, it's as if the if statement is canceled out.

Code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])){
          output_errors($_SESSION['errors']);
          unset($_SESSION['errors']);
          }
```

It should output the error and then unset. It seems as though the unset happens before the if statement.

UPDATE: If the unset is removed, it works as should

output_errors for the ones who wanted it.

```
 function output_errors($error){


        echo '<font color="red">' . $error . '</font>';
                echo '

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

            var blind = document.getElementById("blind");
    var container = document.getElementById("login");
    blind.style.display = "block";
    container.style.display = "block";

            });
    </script>

        ';


    }
```

Comment: Do you start the session (`session_start();`) on every page you use it on?

Comment: yes,and if i take out the unset, it works fine

Comment: Do you have any output buffering or redirecting later in the script?

Comment: @user2067005 what's the code for `output_errors()`

Comment: no, i do not have any redirects, but i do have output buffering of 4096

Comment: @Mr. Alien just the error message and javascript to open the popup

Comment: @user2067005 Ya so include the code with your question

Comment: I suggest you copy the content of `$_SESSION['errors']` into a local variable and output that. Sounds like you have a reference problem, though I don't understand the cause for that.

Answer (score 0):

Don one this, assign this variable to an another and use them as a paramter to output function:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
  $errors = $_SESSION['errors'];
  output_errors($errors);
  unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
```